# Why does AndroidId have a different result between Android and Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have the need to detect a common factor between two apps, one written in Xamarin and one written in Java (Android Studio), running on a users phone.

In the good old days the IMEI did the job nicely. However now I am having to use the Device ID, which is fine for the current purpose, but not perfect.

Anyway, using the following statement in Xamarin gives one result, while using the statement that follows this in Android, gives a different result, both on the same phone.

Why would this be, why is the Device ID not reported as the same value, and is there a way to identify the DeviceID via both platforms that result in the same output ?

Thanks

Xamarin code - Result is "a70c996e74002942"

```
var Device_ID = Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

Android Studio code - Result is "702669b2e9a6f7d1"

```
String Device_ID = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID)

> unique to each combination of app-signing key, user, and device

For privacy reasons, two different apps on the same device will have different ids

Comment: Given this, there are two ways (on Android) to share information between apps. [Shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared) -- all apps can see. [Sharing simple data](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing) -- a mechanism for one app to communicate with another app.

Comment: Thing is, I am currently running multiple different Android apps, and all of those are returning the one same Device_ID as per the above code. 
I need this to identify the individual device back at the server.
I am only seeing the different Device_ID when using Xamarin.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks yes, I am already using this locally on the device, but I need to get the device id (consistent) back to the server.

Comment: Xamarin has no control over this; this is controlled by Android OS. Were your other apps built to target an earlier version of Android, where this was possible? Rebuild them, targeting latest Android, and install them on a new device. Still get same Id?

Comment: According to Google, it is no longer possible to get a true device Id, on current Android version. Make sure you manually uninstall all your old apps, then reinstall with updated versions. To see this new privacy behavior.

Comment: Apps are built for 33 and I have built and rebuilt several times across all apps.